# Reference of duality in Markov Semigroup

Tags: reference-request, markov-chains, semigroup-of-operators

I heard that there is a duality of Markov semigroups acting on functionals or measures, does anyone of a reference of this materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need the [Riesz Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem#The_representation_theorem_for_the_continuous_dual_of_C0(X))

If instead you are interested in Feller semi-groups a good reference is [foundation of modern probability](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4015-8) (lemma 19.13 and proposition 19.14 gives you exactly the "duality" between Feller semi-groups and Feller processes)

If i remember correctly there is also something about general Markov processes in the book [Diffusion, Markov processes and martingales](https://books.google.it/books/about/Diffusions_Markov_Processes_and_Martinga.html?id=eJp330pIvQ4C&redir_esc=y), but i haven't it with me right now, so i can't be sure